# Laravel 10 orderBy on Relationship not working on parent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to create menus and submenus populated from two tables in my database. I am able get what I want working except the menus table does not orderBy correctly. The weight field does not impact the sort. It is sorting by the menu key(id) instead. It works correctly on the submenus however. Any direction would be appreciated. Pretty new to laravel and Eloquent. Thanks in advance. Below is my table structure and code.

```
         menus
+----+-----------+--------+
| id | menu_name | weight |
+----+-----------+--------+
|  1 | Menu1     |      1 |
|  2 | Menu2     |      0 |
+----+-----------+--------+

        sub_menus
+----+-------+--------+---------+
| id | name  | weight | menu_id |
+----+-------+--------+---------+
|  1 | Menu1 |      0 |       2 |
|  2 | Menu2 |      1 |       1 |
+----+-------+--------+---------+
```

Menu Model

```
class Menu extends Model
{
use HasFactory;

public function submenu()
   {
     return $this->hasMany(SubMenu::class)->orderBy('weight', 'ASC');
   }
}
```

SubMenu Model

```
class SubMenu extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function menu()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Menu::class)->orderBy('weight', 'ASC');
    }
}
```

Menu Controller

```
class MenuController extends Controller
{

    public function index(){

    $menu = Menu::all()->load('submenu');
    return $menu;

 }
```

The output is the way I want things structured but if you notice things are not sorting correctly by weight on the menus.

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"menu_name": "Users",
"weight": 1,
"submenu": [
{
     "id": 1,
     "name": "Add user",
     "weight": 0,
     "menu_id": 1
},
{
     "id": 2,
     "name": "Delete User",
     "weight": 1,
     "menu_id": 1
}
]
},
{
 "id": 2,
 "menu_name": "Schedule",
 "weight": 0,
 "submenu": [
{
        "id": 4,
        "name": "View Schedule",
        "weight": 0,
        "menu_id": 2
},
{
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Create Schedule",
        "weight": 1,
        "menu_id": 2
}
]
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I was able to make things work with the below code. However I am wondering if there is a better way to do this. This just doesn't seem like best practice.

Controller

```
class MenuController extends Controller
{

public function index(){

    //get menu items
    $menus = Menu::orderBy('weight', 'ASC')->get()->toArray();
    //create array
    $data = [];
       foreach($menus as $menu){
           $data[]=[
             'id'=>$menu['id'],
             'menu_name'=>$menu['menu_name'],
             'weight'=>$menu['weight'],
             'sub_menu' => $this->getSubMenu($menu['id']),   
            ];
        }
        
    return view('menus',compact('data'));
    
    }


public function getSubMenu($data){

        $data = SubMenu::where(fn($query) => $query->where('menu_id', '=', $data))->orderBy('weight', 'ASC')->get();
        return $data;

}

}
```

View

```
<ul>
@foreach($data as $item)
    <li>
        <a href="{{ $item['weight']; }}">{{ $item['menu_name']; }}</a>
        <ul>
           @foreach ($item['sub_menu'] as $subitem)
           <li><a href="{{ $subitem['weight']; }}">{{ $subitem['name']; }}</a></li>
           @endforeach 
        </ul>
    </li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try ->orderBy(..) instead of ->orderby(..)

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#chunking-results

Comment: Ya tried this too. No change. Menu still sorts by id not weight. Submenu works great.